# Dll Access not Working When Switching Startup Projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, ghostscript

I am currently developing a program that uses the Ghost Script DLL, by importing it as so:

```
[DllImport("gsdll32.dll", EntryPoint = "gsapi_init_with_args")]
```

Now, when I set the project in my solution that uses this directly (located in the directory`...\source\repos\uo_test_viewer\omr_scanner\omrmarkengine-master`) as the startup project, everything works fine. However, when I change my startup project to a project located in `...\source\repos\uo_test_viewer\UOTestViewer`, I get the following error:

```
The gsdll32.dll wasn't found in the default search path or is not in correct version 

(doesn't expose required methods). Please download at least the version 8.64 from the original website.
```

The only thing that is being changed is that when I set the project that makes this work as the startup project, I am running it directly -- where as with the project that doesn't work, I am creating an object of the form that uses the Ghost Script implementation. Does anybody know what the issue is?

I believe that I have provided all the necessary information, but please let me know if anything more is required. Thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DllImport looks first in the current working directory, then in the search path (the $PATH) environment variable).

When you start your application in the folder which contains the Ghostscript DLL, then the Windows API call DllImport looks in the current working directory and finds the Ghostscript DLL, so it loads it.

When you start in a directory which does not contain the Ghostscript DLL, then DllImport looks in the Current Working Directory, and does not find the DLL. It then searches the search path, which presumably does not find a Ghostscript DLL, so you get an error.

You either need to be sure the current working directory has a copy of the Ghostscritp DLL, or the DLL is on the search path, or you need to supply a fully qualified path to the Ghostscript DLL in the first argument to DllImport.

In case you are considering distributing this application, please read the AGPL license to ensure that you comply with the terms for using Ghostscript.